# preserve context of variable assigned to an instance method

Tags: javascript

This has been eluding me. Take the following code:

```
function tSt( val ) {
    this.val = val;
}

tSt.func = function( x ) {
    return x * 2;
}

tSt.prototype.func = function() {
    return tSt.func( this.val );
}

var tmp = new tSt( 5 );

console.log( tmp.func());  // 10

var other = tmp.func;

console.log( other());  // undefined
```

The reason I want to be able to do this is for something like the following scenario:

```
(function( funcarr ) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < funcarr.length; i++ )
        console.log( funcarr[i]());
})([ tmp.func ]);
```

How can this be accomplished?

**Update:**

Here's a potentially more global solution, but I'm not sure if there are any drawbacks to doing it this way:

```
function tSt( val ) {
    this.val = val;
    this.func = this.func.bind( this );
}

tSt.func = function( x ) {
    return x * 2;
}

tSt.prototype.func = function() {
    return tSt.func( this.val );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Function#bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
var other = tmp.func.bind(tmp);
```

This ensures that whenever `other` is called, the `this` pointer will be `tmp`.

Since `bind` is not implemented in all browsers, you may need a polyfill like the one given in the above link. (In fact, I recommend you go all the way and get an [ES5 shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim).)

---

If you're willing to abandon prototypal inheritance, which is necessary if you want to pass methods around without remembering to `bind` them, then I instead suggest the [module pattern](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html):

```
function TSt(val) {
   // save a reference to our current "this" so that, even inside of methods
   // called from other contexts, we still have it.
   var that = this;

   that.val = val;
   that.func = function () {
       return that.val * 2;
       // Since we're using that instead of this, still works even without bind.
   }
}

var tmp = new TSt(5);
var other = tmp.func;
console.log(other()); // 10
```

Indeed, another major benefit of this pattern is you can get private variables:

```
function Encapsulated(mine, public) {
    var that = this;

    var private = mine * 2;

    that.public = public;
    that.compute = function () {
        return that.public * private;
    };
}
```

Now consumers of an `Encapsulated` instance have no access to `mine` or `private`, but only to `public`.

Comment: whoa, that was fast. That solution works. Mind taking a look at my update and letting me know what you think?

Comment: The updated example works, but it loses the benefit of prototypal inheritance, because now you are creating a separate `func` property for each instance of `tSt`. That `func` just so happens to be related to `tSt.prototype.func`, but that's really irrelevant, because no callers will ever see the prototypally-inherited `func`, just the one specific to your new instance. In other words, your code is the same as `this.func = (function (x) { return x * 2 }).bind(this);`.

Comment: Makes sense, but guess loosing the benefit is necessary if I want to be able to simply pass `other.func` as a function parameter instead of `other.func.bind( tmp )`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Nice, I like it. Now I don't have to worry about implementing `bind` in browsers that don't support it. Great follow up.